# Eclipse plugins - Add a menucontribution to Toolbar dynamically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to add `menucontribution`, basically a new button, to the `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar` dynamically?

I tried with `AbstractContributionFactory` but it seems to be bugged, since the `createContributionItems` [is never called](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411765).

My code so far tries to add a new button to the Eclipse toolbar after pressing another button. The thing is that the `createContributionItems` is never called so "Creating Stuff" never appears:

```
//If a certain button is pressed run will be executed
public void run(IAction action) {

        MessageDialog.openInformation(
            window.getShell(),
            "Runtimecommands",
            "Hello, Eclipse world");



          IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);

          AbstractContributionFactory factory = new AbstractContributionFactory("toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar", null) 

            @Override
            public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IContributionRoot additions) {

            System.out.println("Creating Stuff");


          };    
          menuService.addContributionFactory(factory); 

}
```

And my current plugin.xml

```
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
      <actionSet
            label="Sample Action Set"
            visible="true"
            id="com.dynamo.actionSet">
         <menu
               label="Sample &amp;Menu"
               id="sampleMenu">
            <separator
                  name="sampleGroup">
            </separator>
         </menu>
         <action
               label="&amp;Sample Action"
               icon="icons/sample.gif"
               class="com.dynamo.actions.SampleAction"
               tooltip="Hello, Eclipse world"
               menubarPath="sampleMenu/sampleGroup"
               toolbarPath="sampleGroup"
               id="com.dynamo.actions.SampleAction">
         </action>
      </actionSet>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Tks for your attention.

Comment: Please show your code that you tried so far.

Comment: I added the code i use so far. Also i use: Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: Don't you need to use `CommandContributionItem` of `STYLE_PUSH`  if you want a button?

Comment: You also need to add the class that performs this dynamic addition to your plugin.xml, if you already did please show your plugin.xml.

Comment: Hi! Yes i already tried with CommandContribution with STYLE_PUSH and other things. The problem is that the createContributionItem that does that stuff is never called.

Comment: It will be called once you add an entry of type `menuContribution` to your plugin.xml

Comment: Also after you push your existing button, you might need to refresh the view to see new command in case you were successful in hitting the `createContributionItem`

Comment: I just followed the example at http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/dynamic-menu-items-eclipse.html and added a menucontribution with dynamic. But the first menu doenst even appear if the location URI is toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar, with other locations like menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu it does appear. 
And this solution i think is more to populate a given existing menu with items and not create a new menu in another location for example. tks for your attetion.

Comment: Also tried refreshing all views and current perspective but once again createContributionItems is never called.